# Double linked list C programming

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a double linked list with strings. The problem is that when I send a word and try to print it out - only the first letter (the ASCII value) comes out. For example if I write "Joe" I will get 74 back (74 is the ASCII value of "J")

I do remember something to do with strncopy but can't recall. Any suggestions? :)

```
struct Item
{
    char e;
    Position previous;
    Position next;
};
 
void Insert(char x, List l, Position p)
{
    Position TmpCell;
    TmpCell = (struct Item*) malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
    if(TmpCell == NULL)
        printf("Memory out of space\n");
    else
    {
        TmpCell->e = x;
        TmpCell->previous = p;
        TmpCell->next = p->next;
        p->next = TmpCell;
    }
}
```

This is the method used to display:

```
void Display(List l)
{

    printf("The list element are :: ");
    Position p = l->next;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ", p->e);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Faults - it just didnt work as expected

Comment: Not using '%d' would help.  Google for 'printf format strings'.

Comment: What is `List`? What is `Position`? How are these functions called? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that contains the smallest, **complete** code required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Item previous` and `Item next` if you want to access Item's fields as you do in the `else` branch in function Insert?

Comment: You imply this is a linked list that holds strings, but it is not. It holds one character per node.

Comment: OT: apparently `Position` is a pointer hidden behind  a `typedef`. Don't do this, this is very bad practice and only creates confusion and makes your code less readable.

Answer (score -2):

you can try

```
printf("%c",p->e);
```

Comment: They want to print a string. The actual problem is the list node only stores a single `char`, not a null-terminated string. This doesn’t answer the question.